# Algorithm to determine if an interval is covered by a list of intervals?

Tags: algorithms, intervals

Given a list of intervals $[s_1, e_1], [s_2, e_2], \ldots$, what's the most efficient way to determine if an interval $[a, b]$ can be covered by the intervals in the list?

Comment: You might want to take a look at the algorithm used to reassemble fragmented IP datagrams. This has to determine when all the fragments have been received, which corresponds to covering the interval from 0 to `size`.

Comment: This is a dump of a problem, not a question. If you have a specific question regarding the wording of the problem or about concrete steps in your own attempts at solving the problem, feel free to edit accordingly and we can reopen the question. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a relevant discussion. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Comment: Um, no, this is a question, hence the question mark. I have thought about this, but there is no reason to clutter the question with my work. I vote for it to be reopened, as it is an interesting problem.

Comment: If you need a working solution for this problem in C++ - look at the Boost ICL library (`http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/icl/doc/html/index.html`). However, their implementation is not easy to extract from their sources.

Comment: I agree with Raphael.  Related: We expect you to do some serious research on your own before asking, and to show us what you've tried.  So, what research have you done?  Hint: if you search on "interval" on this site and look through the first few search results, you'll immediately find some references to data structures for storing intervals, which then apply directly to your problem.  This is a sign that you haven't done enough research before asking.  In fact, it looks like the very first search result gives a solution to your problem: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/14311/755

Comment: Hint: A [segment tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree) should solve your problem immediately, with no extra work needed, and give a very efficient solution.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's the **most** efficient algorithm, but here's my suggestion:

Your problem is somewhat similar to balancing parenthesis: you can put all $s_i$ and $e_i$ values on a list and sort it (Lets call this list $V$), but keep the type of each element ($s$ or $e$ element) attached to the value. Then use this list to integrate all the intervals with the following algorithm (uniting overlapping intervals to one interval):

```
create a list of intervals L, Create a stack St
for every element n in the sorted list V (from the smallest to the largest)
{
    if n is an s element and St is empty
    {
         create a new interval I (a pair of numbers)
         assign I.s = n
         push some value to St
    }

    else if n is an s element and St isn't empty
    {
         push some value to St
    }

    else if n is an e element (stack can't be empty here)
    {
         pop a value from St
         if St is empty
         {
               assign I.e = n
               add interval I to the interval list L
         }
   }
}

return L
```

Now you have a list of integrated intervals, and checking if $[a,b]$ si covered by one of them is easy: for every interval $I$ in $L$, check if $a \geq I.s$ and $b \leq I.e$ (there are no overlapping intervals in $L$ now, they were integrated in the previous step).

Integrating the intervals to create $L$ takes $O(n)$ computation time and so is checking if $[a,b]$ is covered by one of the intervals in $L$, which makes the sorting $V$ the most expensive task here, $O(n\log{n})$.

Hope this helps, though there might be a linear time algorithm for performing this task...

Comment: Please try to not encourage [undesirable posting behaviour](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question).

Comment: This is not homework. This is a question of mine and I'm curious to know the answer. I doubt any of my thoughts on solving this would be helpful, since I basically got nowhere. I submit for this question to be reopened.